# Wordpress : Change title of sidebar widget dynamically

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to get the title of the widgets that I have enabled in my sidebar so I can insert that as a name for my class attribute?

For example:
`'before_title' => <h2 class="title of the widget">',`

If I inspect the element, I want to see:
`<h2 class="author">` and `<h2 class="links">` etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's definitely possible, but if you want to do it dynamically, you'd need to use a filter.

The `dynamic_sidebar_params` filter should work for you. If you're unfamiliar with what filters do, basically a filter allows you to edit content before it's displayed on screen or saved in the database. See more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference

In the `dynamic_sidebar_params` filter, the passed array has the following structure (I got this from doing a print_r)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Primary Widget Area
            [id] => primary-widget-area
            [description] => The primary widget area
            [before_widget] => <li id="search-2" class="widget-container widget_search">
            [after_widget] => </li>
            [before_title] => <h3 class="widget-title">
            [after_title] => </h3>
            [widget_id] => search-2
            [widget_name] => Search
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [number] => 2
        )

)
```

So that means, all you have to do is edit the `$params` array before returning it. You might have to do some conditional logic as well to get the exact class that you want, but I'll leave that up to you.

Here is an example:

```
function my_edit_widget_func($params) {
    $params[0]['before_title'] = '<h3 class="' . $params[0]['widget_name'] . '">' ;
    return $params;
}
add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params', 'my_edit_widget_func');
```

Comment: This is perfect.  I will try this out right now and let you know how it goes!

Comment: I added this function in 'functions.php' along with the add_filter call.  Is this the proper place to put it?  I am relatively new to WordPress so this is a little confusing for me.