# Overriding Parent Theme Functions in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the free "responsive" Wordpress theme for my website, and using Child Themes for the first time.

I need to add a div tag underneath the widgets `<h3>` tag, but the sidebar functions where the tag resides is stored in the parents functions, and I'm having trouble overriding the function in my Child Theme.

This is what I have to try and remove the Parents Sidebar Function, and re-add my own, however it's not removing the sidebar:

The original function to add sidebars looks idential to my function `child_responsive_widgets_init()`, but it's called `responsive_widgets_init()` if that helps.

```
<?php

function child_responsive_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
                          'name'          => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'responsive' ),
                          'description'   => __( 'Area 1 - sidebar.php - Displays on Default, Blog, Blog Excerpt page templates', 'responsive' ),
                          'id'            => 'main-sidebar',
                          'before_title'  => '<div class="widget-title"><h3>',
                          'after_title'   => '</h3><em>&nbsp;</em></div>',
                          'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-wrapper %2$s">',
                          'after_widget'  => '</div>'
                      ) );
}
function remove_parent_widgets() {
    remove_action( 'widgets_init', 'responsive_widgets_init' );
}
add_action('init','remove_parent_widgets');

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'parent_unregister_sidebars' );
function parent_unregister_sidebars() {
    unregister_sidebar( 'main-sidebar' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'child_responsive_widgets_init' );
?>
```

Comment: Go and have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6080097/1908141) answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have to [wait until `functions.php` file is loaded](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request), then we can intercept the parent's hook.

Add this to your child's `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_parent_hook_so_22995302' );

function remove_parent_hook_so_22995302()
{
    remove_action( 'widgets_init', 'responsive_widgets_init' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This totally worked! I didn't need to use the unregister_sidebar either. I'll post my updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

<sub><sup>*Moved [from the Question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22995302/3) into an answer.*</sup></sub>

Thanks to brasofilo and his solution I've got the functions file overriding properly. Here's the updated code below if anyone wants to know.

```
function child_responsive_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
          'name'          => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'responsive' ),
          'description'   => __( 'Area 1 - sidebar.php - Displays on Default, Blog, Blog Excerpt page templates', 'responsive' ),
          'id'            => 'main-sidebar',
          'before_title'  => '<div class="widget-title"><h3>',
          'after_title'   => '</h3><em>&nbsp;</em></div>',
          'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-wrapper %2$s">',    
          'after_widget'  => '</div>'
      ) );
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','remove_parent_widgets');

function remove_parent_widgets() {
    remove_action( 'widgets_init', 'responsive_widgets_init' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'child_responsive_widgets_init' );
```