# How to assign aria label to sidebar aside

Tags: php, wordpress, function, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm going through a client's site using Siteimprove's chrome extension to test for compliance. I'm getting a "Landmarks with identical names" error on two asides in one sidebar area. In the register sidebar code in functions.php, I have:

```
'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s" aria-label="Job Openings and Events">',
```

This is working and assigning the label, but there are two widgets in this sidebar (a text widget and events list widget) and Wordpress is creating an aside for each with the same label. Is there some sort of nth assignment or something I can do to assign each aside in this sidebar with a different label to prevent redundancy?

Answer (score 1):

See this example,

```
function my_edit_widget_func($params) {
$params[0]['before_widget'] = '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s" aria-label="' . $params[0]['widget_name'] . '">' ;
return $params;
}
add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params', 'my_edit_widget_func');
```

Hope this will helps you. For more information please visit.

1. [dynamic_sidebar Function to Generate Class](http://www.humbug.in/2010/custom-dynamic_sidebar-function-to-generate-class-definitions-corresponding-to-a-widgets-position/)
2. [Add class to specific widget in WordPress](https://mekshq.com/how-to-add-last-class-to-wordpress-footer-widget/)
3. [Wordpress : Change title of sidebar widget dynamically
   Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078112/wordpress-change-title-of-sidebar-widget-dynamically)

Comment: It is still just coming up as aria-label="Text"

Answer (score 1):

```
register_sidebar(array(  
    'name' => 'Footer #2',  
    'id'   => 'footer2',  
    'description'   => 'Footer widget 2',  
    'before_widget' => '<aside role="complementary" id="%1$s" class="widget-content footer-widget" aria-label="[title]">',  
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',  
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title footer-widget-title">',  
    'after_title'   => '</h2>' ,
));

    function stp_accessibility_widget_func($params) {
    $name = isset($params[0]['widget_name']) ? $params[0]['widget_name'] : "";
    $params[0]['before_widget'] = str_replace('[title]', esc_attr($name), $params[0]['before_widget'] );
    return $params;
}
add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params', 'stp_accessibility_widget_func');
```

Use this solution it will add aria-label in all the widgets