# Filter Wordpress widgets to add widget title as h2 id

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, tags, widget

I have created a one page Wordpress website with jump links to various sections however the Contact section is a widget and doesn't have a nice looking human readable id attribute (`id="wpforms-widget-3"`) meaning when the link is clicked on, it won't be clear from the URL that it's the contact section e.g. currently looks like www.example.com/#wpforms-widget-3 instead of www.example.com/#contact

How can I change the output of the widgets to include the widget title as an h2 id attribute?

Currently, the contact widget looks like `<h2 class="widget-title">Contact</h2>`

It needs to be: **`<h2 id="Contact" class="widget-title">Contact</h2>`**

Google is not my friend tonight and while I can find things like how to add additional HTML tags and sections or change h2 to hx, I can't find anything for getting the widget title and adding it to the existing h2 tag as an id.

Closest I have found so far is:

```
function add_widget_name_id($params) {

    $params[0]['before_title'] = '<h2 id="' . $params[0]['widget_name'] . '" class="widget-title">' ;
    return $params;
}
add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params', 'add_widget_name_id');
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6080097/5204226

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do anything and the h2 tag still only contains class and not the needed id.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is working fine on my side. I just checked this and it worked perfectly..

Comment: I really don't know what's going wrong then. I am using this code via Code Snippets plugin (other code snippet is working fine). But the h2 tag remains untouched: https://imgur.com/MUleedv

Comment: Something to do with the widget being in the footer instead of a 'sidebar'?

Comment: I think the problems lies within the plugin.. create a child theme and try

Comment: It's not the plugin. I tried adding it directly to the Twenty Seventeen functions.php as a test and it made no difference. I decided to try adding the same type of widget to the theme's sidebar (instead of the footer where the current widgets are) and that works: https://imgur.com/OOjXIGc
So the issue is that the code isn't being applied to widgets in the footer.

Comment: Actually, I just realised it's not working like that either as the id attribute is "teXt" not "Test". So the id is being set as the widget type instead of the widget name/title.